# Content Length header is not present in Http response with Azure function v1

Tags: azure, azure-functions

We have azure function which is running with azure v1 (.NET Framework 4.7). In http response, we are trying to set the content length but it is not flowing to client. It sets the Transfer encoding header with value as chunked.
To give glimpse of how we are setting it.

```
var body = <some byte array data>
var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(body);
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = body.Length;
```

I went through some [online discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/7ceb818f-5e8c-42ff-b2ec-c0aa3f9094a2/app-service-suddenlt-started-to-respond-with-chunked-encoding-where-it-used-to-response-with?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) and [Azure/azure-functions-host#3765](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3765)
There they talked about setting up,

```
response.Headers.TransferEncoding.Add(TransferCodingHeaderValue.Parse("identity"))
```

But it seems to be of no use.
Would anyone faced such kind of issue before?
BTW, when I ran the same code on azure function v2 (.NET Core 2.2) it works.

Update: Transfer-Encoding header we could see through packet capture using wireshark.
[Wireshark screenshot depicting Transfer-Encoding header even if content-length is set through code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JE36d.png)

Update-2 : This is happening for function running locally. When we publish the function on azure it does provide the content length header. Locally, I guess it (v1) uses nodejs simulator which seems to have some issue. Anyway, will update here once we find out any workaround.

Answer (score 2):

**Content-length can't be set if the Transfer-Encoding is set to be chunked**. `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` isn't needed for progressive rendering. However, it is needed when the total content length is unknown before the first bytes are sent.

Basically, the decimal value of the content-length in OCTETs represents both the entity-length and the transfer-length. If there is some transfer-encoding, then these two lengths will be different and consequently the content-length value should be ignored.

I test with your code in function v1 without `Transfer-Encoding` it work well too.

[image]

So if you want to set specific content length, you could remove `Transfer-Encoding`.

Comment: Thanks Joey for quick response. When we view the headers in debug inspection mode it does show the Content-Length **BUT** when it flows to client, we could still see Transfer-Encoding: chunked through packet capture using wireshark. Have updated the question with wireshark screenshot. I also tried to explicitly remove the Header : `response.Headers.Remove("Transfer-Encoding")` But this also does not work.      Also, same thing works with Azure function V2. My guess there must be some internal processing that Azure function V1 is doing that is not happening in V2